Why does linux deny permission to establish a Java Jsch session when the war file is deployed in a Tomcat server?
I have been trying to establish a Jsch session in a Java Spring Controller, so I can execute a shell script. The session is established and commands are run during local testing and manually testing on machine, but failing to connect with

java.net.SocketException : Permission Denied, Connect Failed message in the war file deployed in tomcat on the same machine.

The following code executes when I run on my machine, and also the deployment machine when I login into it and run the class using java RunClass but not when the classes are packed into a war file and deployed into the tomcat. I get this message at either session.connect() or channelExec.connect() code.

java.net.SocketException : Permission Denied, Connect Failed

Why does this behaviour occur?
Earlier, when I was using ProcessBuilder class, I was also able to execute commands on the machine but not via war deployed on tomcat. I had to face Permission Denied, Cannot Execute command chmod (or command conda).
Controller.java
@RequestMapping(value="/endpoint", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Response<String> generateOrderTrail2(@RequestParam("id) String id){

ScriptCaller scriptCaller = new ScriptCaller();
scriptCaller.setId(id);
scriptCaller.executeCommand();

if(scriptCaller.isSuccessful()){
   return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body("Successful");
}
else{
   return ResponseEntity.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body("Unsuccessful");
}

}

ScriptCaller.java
boolean isSuccessful = false;
public void executeCommand(){
   String command = './dir/folder/executeFile.sh';
try{
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(this.username, this.hostname, 22);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);

session.setPassword(this.password);
session.connect();
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
channelExec.setInputStream((InputStream)null);
InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(channelExec.getInputStream());
channelExec.setInputStream((InputStream) null);
channelExec.setCommand(command);
channelExec.connect();
char[] buffer = new char[128];
int read;
while ((read=stream.read(buffer 0, buffer.length))>=0){
output.append(buffer, 0, read);
}
this.callerResponse = outputString.toString();
int exitCode = channelExec.getExitStatus();
channelExec.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
if(exitCode == 0){
 System.out.println("Shell Script Executed Successfully");
 isSuccessful = true;
}
else{
 System.out.println("Shell Script Failed to Execute");
 isSuccessful = false;

}
}
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  isSuccessful = false;
}

Maven Build Command.
mvn clean deploy -Denvironment=local -Dskip.webapp=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Exception
java.net.SocketException: Permission Denied(connect failed)
..
..
..
..
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java)

Tomcat version 7.0.76.0
I checked if the non-root user doesn't have permission or the file doesn't have execute permissions,
The shell file has rwx on all users (777 permissions).
The same file is executable with the same user when tested locally or when the code is run inside a single java file if I login and run on the machine.
It's just denying permissions when I call the end point after deploying war file in the tomcat server

Is SSH enabled in the server? Is the port open?

Yes @aled , I was able to ssh via putty into the machine and also, I can use JSch to connect to the machine from local desktop

How do you execute your Tomcat? (a) Use System Service (b) Or directly execute ./startup.sh under your user account to execute Tomcat?

Your Tomcat service account should create a privateKey for ssh use, or specify the privateKey in your program.  String privateKey = "path_to_your_private_key"; jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);

hi @life888888, Thnx for following up! I'm using (b) running the starup.sh command. Do I add need to add private key if I am following (b)?

ScriptCaller.java - Try to modify String command = './dir/folder/executeFile.sh'; to the complete path. For example: String command = '/home/xyz/Downloads/dir/folder/executeFile.sh'; (2)

(1) Jsch version ? (2) Spring version ? (3) executeFile.sh content ?
